# go mod tidy "all" matched no packages

Tags: go, package, go-modules

I've created a go module using this:

```bash
go mod init rtws
vim main.go # pasted a bunch of code from an example
go mod tidy
```

Both of these files import "github.com/gorilla/websocket", so when I used `tidy` I expected that it would download that dependency, but instead I got the following warning:

`go: warning: "all" matched no packages`

And subsequently trying to run it complained that the dependency did not exist.
**What does this error mean?**

EDIT: when searching, the most relevant thing I found was [this other question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355472/golang-matched-no-packages-error-with-absolute-path-fine-with-relative-path).  A lot of people had this warning come up when running other commands but their solutions didn't work for this particular situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out what caused the issue while I was writing the question.  At the top of the code that I pasted were the following lines:

```golang
//go:build ignore
// +build ignore
```

So, apparently this warning means there were no files in the module.  The effect of the above lines tells go's build system to ignore that file, so `go mod tidy` behaved in the same way it would have if that file didn't exist.

Removing these allowed go mod tidy to do what I originally expected it to.  Being new to golang this feature was not on the top of things I would have considered.